# Колонки таблицы равной ширины

Tags: html, css, table

Я создаю таблицу и выставляю в процентах ширину каждого столбца. Для примера, второй столбец должен иметь ширину в 30%, четвертый — 10% .Это работает во многих случаях, но, если название колонки длинное, ширина всего столбца расширяется до ширина названия колонки. Каким образом можно избежать такого поведения, создать таблицу с жестко выставленной (в процентах) шириной столбцов?

```css
table {
  width: 100%
}

table>tbody>tr>td {
  width: 20%
}

table>thead>tr>th {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 30%
}

table>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(4) {
  width: 10%
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan=3>Group 1</th>
      <th colspan=2>Group 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan=1>Group 3</th>
      <th colspan=4>Group 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>TooLongColumn4Title</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td>Value 3</td>
      <td>Value 4</td>
      <td>Value 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td>Value 3</td>
      <td>Value 4</td>
      <td>Value 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td>Value 3</td>
      <td>Value 4</td>
      <td>Value 5</td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
  
</table>
```

Comment: Проблему мог бы решить colgroup, но он перекрывает стили thead, «стирает» нужные границы в сложной многоуровневой шапке таблицы

Answer (score 0):

Задайте таблице **word-break: break-all**

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  word-break: break-all;
}
table>tbody>tr>td {
  width: 20%
}

table>thead>tr>th {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 30%
}

table>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(4) {
  width: 10%
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan=3>Group 1</th>
      <th colspan=2>Group 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan=1>Group 3</th>
      <th colspan=4>Group 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>TooLongColumn4Titlesfsgfsfgsdfg</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td>Value 3</td>
      <td>Value 4</td>
      <td>Value 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td>Value 3</td>
      <td>Value 4</td>
      <td>Value 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td>Value 3</td>
      <td>Value 4</td>
      <td>Value 5</td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
  
</table>
```

Comment: Ну а где здесь ширина 2 колонки в 30 % и 4 в 10 %?

Comment: А причём здесь это? Проблема, как следует из вопроса, в том, что длинный текст растягивает ячейку. Это проблема решена. Ширину задавайте какую хотите.

Comment: Ну я же написал в вопросе «Для примера, второй столбец должен иметь ширину в 30%, четвертый — 10%» должен иметь — ключевое слово

Comment: @Alaksander, я поправил ответ - теперь это то, что надо?